# Nested Serializer for Django to nest subfields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a viewset which retrieves a queryset (`Region.objects.filter(id=region_id)`), and I want to serialize the queryset to include a number of tables referenced by foreign key like so:

`Region` >> `Market` >> `Baskets` >> `Fruits`

Each `fruit` has a `basket_id`

Each `basket` has a `market_id`

Each `market` has a `region_id`

I have a serializer:

```
class RegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    markets = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_markets(self, obj):
        return ==(list(obj.region_set.all().filter(region_id=obj.id).values()))
```

So far this works great to retrieve the market list, but I want to nest it so I have a region, a list of individual markets on the region, a list of individual baskets on each market, and a list of individual fruits on each basket.

I'm not entirely sure how to accomplish said subfields using the serializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work? You'd need to use the `related_name` for the FK relations I think e.g. in the example below, the FK between fruit and basket would be set with `related_name='fruit'`

```
class FruitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Fruit
        fields = '__all__'

class BasketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    fruit = FruitSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Basket
        fields = '__all__'

class MarketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    baskets = BasketSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Market
        fields = '__all__'

class RegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    markets = MarketSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = '__all__'
```

Worth also considering performance implications of nesting a load of stuff like this. Might end up hitting the DB a lot.

Comment: well, you were faster than me ;) but I'd like to point out that the `depth` option could also come in handy for that:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: and, nested Serializers are *NOT* writeable on default. You would have to write your own save() method.

Comment: ah yeah they're both really good points! Thanks for highlighting them :)